# Google App Engine NDB Queries and exceeding memory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have a Google App Engine datastore kind called "Obj" and it has close to 500K entities in production. I'm trying to query just 50 Obj entities, but even though I'm setting the limit argument to 50, the query eventually throws the error "Exceeded soft private memory limit".

Would this have something to do with the use of ndb.GenericProperty in the query? The attribute "trashed_date", which is a datetime type, is not normally an attribute of Obj. I've also manually created the correct index for status and trashed_date. Should "trashed_date" always be a property of that model?

Below is the code I'm using, what can I do so when querying just 50 entities it doesn't exceed the memory limit?

```
q = Obj.query(
    Obj.status == 1,
    ndb.GenericProperty('trashed_date') < expire_date
)
results = q.fetch(50)
```

Comment: I doubt it it has anything to do with the generic property.  Though if the Obj class doesn't have a trashed_date property why are you querying for it?  How big are the entities you are retrieving.  Does the error occur each time you run the query or over time ?

Comment: It always throws the error. The thought is that very few of the Obj's will ever have the "trashed_date" property. Each entity shouldn't be very large, no more than 1K.

Comment: You might want to profile you app.  See https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/wiki/UsingApptrace  .  As an aside you do realize that entities that don't have the trashed_date property will never be returned with this query.

Comment: Yes, not getting entities that do not have the trashed_date property is perfectly fine.

Comment: It might be worth an experiment. add 'trashed_date' into the Obj model as a DatetimeProperty and then do the query `Obj.query().filter(Obj.status == 1,Obj.trashed_date < expire_date)` just to exclude the possibility of problem using GenericProperty against a DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this using q.iter() and a counter to limit it to 50. I had a similar problem with fetch() and fixed it using iter(). GAE is pretty strongly advising against fetch now. YMMV. HTH. -stevep

Comment: Do you have a reference for the statement against using `fetch`? I thought I read that too, but didn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Quote: "Note: You should rarely need to use this method[fetch]; it is almost always better to use run() instead." note: db is run(), ndb is iter() ] Link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Seems like it should be mentioned in the ndb docs if  `iter` has the same limitations.

Comment: Sean, iter() is the ndb equivalent of db's run() so it is also the preferred alternative to fetch() as above. In other places (which I do not want to track down) fetch is described as a wrapper for run/iter. My guess is that when you fetch(50) you may be having the underlying code simply do the iteration for you, and receiving a list of 50 entities. If those entities have much in the way of sizable properties, then you will hit a soft memory limit for your instance (as I did). Fetch is easier since there is no counter overhead, so it has its purpose for lightweight stuff. HTH. -stevep

Comment: itertools.islice makes a good fetch-like wrapper around iter(). results = islice(query.iter(), offset, page_size + offset)